# Why dosn't "must_not" work when I query on the indicest hat do not contain the term.

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a ES indice that looks like this:

```
     "_source" : {
      "text_terms" : [
        {
          "term" : "aaa",
          "freq" : 1
        },
        {
          "term" : "西门子",
          "freq" : 1
        },
        {
          "term" : "ccc",
          "freq" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
```

and the mapping is here:

```
        "text_terms":{
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{
                "term":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "index":"not_analyzed"
                },
                "freq":{
                    "type":"integer"
                }
             }
    }
```

now I want to query the docs which contain `西门子`

```
"query": {
   "nested": {
      "query": {
         "bool": {
          "must": [{
             "term": { 
               "text_terms.term": "西门子" }
                    }]
                 }
               },
              "path": "text_terms" 
             } 
          }
```

it works. But when I want to query the docs which do not contains `西门子`

```
"query":
     { "nested":
         { "query": {
             "bool": {
               "must_not": [{
                      "term": {
                         "text_terms.term": "西门子" }
                       }]
                   }
                },
           "path": "text_terms" }
           }
```

why this time it does not work, I could query all docs even do not contain `西门子` e.g.

```
   "_source" : {
      "text_terms" : [
        {
          "term" : "ddd",
          "freq" : 1
        },
        {
          "term" : "eee",
          "freq" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

From [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/26264) I know the right query, that is should put `must_not` outside `nested`, see below

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "text_terms",
                "query": {
                    "term": {
                        "text_terms.term": "西门子"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```